# how can I update the record in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am storing the various activities with id's as 1,2,3,4 consecutively.

If I delete the 2nd record (id 2), how can I update so that 3 becomes 2 and 4 becomes 3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It shouldn't matter if there are gaps. Both Oracle and SQL Server support `ROW_NUMBER` if you need to derive a contiguous sequence of numbers from the ids.

Comment: The question isn't how, but why?  What are you trying to accomplish by guaranteeing consecutive numbers STORED and MAINTAINED in the table?

Comment: *frds*... Is that an abbreviation of *fjords*?

Answer (score 1):

```
update table set col1 = col1-1 where col1>2
```

Comment: If the OP is using an actual `identity` column in SQL Server this won't work as they are not updatable.

Comment: @Martin - yups thats true that you cannot change

Comment: what is OP?Here please let me know

Comment: "OP" means "original poster" -- in this case, you.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1. You don't want to. The whole purpose of an id field is thet it is immutable.

Answer 2. You don't want to. If you need to do it, the id field isn't an id field at all, but a data field.

Answer 3. Delete the records and insert them again with the new numbers. 
You can see that this gets very expensive if the number of rows is big.

Comment: in many cases, if you delete and reinsert, the deleted ids won't be reused, instead the new unused ID in the sequence will be used

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) approach instead, where each activity points to the next?

```
select * from activity;
+----+---------+
| id | next_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       2 |
|  2 |       3 |
|  3 |       4 |
|  4 |       5 |
|  5 |    NULL |
+----+---------+
```

If you want to delete the activity with ID=2, you need to update the row that points to ID=2 to the row that ID=2 previously pointed to.

```
update activity
   set next_id = 3
 where id = 1;

delete
  from activity 
 where id = 2;

+----+---------+
| id | next_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       3 |
|  3 |       4 |
|  4 |       5 |
|  5 |    NULL |
+----+---------+
```

If you have very long lists and are worried about DML performance, this may be a good option. The drawback of this method is that it is harder to query the table.

Comment: +1 But wouldn't this be better described as a [singly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singly_linked_list)?

Comment: @oneday, yes, I updated the answer to use the correct terminology.